# Extract raw mail from html tag

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have 30B rows. My data frame looks like

```
age                          email
33    </style></head><body lang="EN-IN"link="#0563C1" vlink="#954F72">. 
      <divclass="WordSection1"><p class="MsoNormal"><spanstyle="font- 
      family:&quot;Calibri&quot;,sans-serif; color:black">Iam not interested. 
      Please unsubscribe me.&nbsp;</span></p><pclass="MsoNormal">
      <spanstyle="font-family:&quot;Calibri&quot;,sans-serif;color:black">&nbsp;

22    </style></head><body lang="EN-IN"link="#0563C1" vlink="#954F72"> 
      <divclass="WordSection1"><p class="MsoNormal"><spanstyle="font- 
      family:&quot;Calibri&quot;,sans-serif;color:black">Please share company 
      details</span></p><divclass="MsoNormal" align="center"style="text- 
      align:center"><hr size="2"width="98%" align="center"></div> 
      <pclass="MsoNormal">

43    </style></head><body lang="EN-IN"link="#0563C1" vlink="#954F72"> 
      <divclass="WordSection1"><p class="MsoNormal"><spanstyle="font- 
      family:&quot;Calibri&quot;,sans-serif;color:black">Can you send 
      some project info for west region ofIndia</span></p><p class="MsoNormal"> 
      <spanstyle="font-family:&quot;Calibri&quot;,sans-serif;color:black">

38    </style></head><bodylang="EN-IN" link="#0563C1"vlink="#954F72"><div 
      class="WordSection1"><pclass="MsoNormal"><span style="font- 
     family:&quot;Calibri&quot;,sans-serif;color:black">Price of Mono perc</span> 
     </p><divclass="MsoNormal" align="center"style="text-align:center"><hr 
     size="2"width="98%" align="center"></div><pclass="MsoNormal"><b>
```

My final dataframe looks like -

```
age                          email                                                   text
33    </style></head><body lang="EN-IN"link="#0563C1" vlink="#954F72">.      Iam not interested. 
      <divclass="WordSection1"><p class="MsoNormal"><spanstyle="font-        Please unsubscribe
      family:&quot;Calibri&quot;,sans-serif; color:black">Iam not interested. me.
      Please unsubscribe me.&nbsp;</span></p><pclass="MsoNormal">
      <spanstyle="font-family:&quot;Calibri&quot;,sans-serif;color:black">&nbsp;

22    </style></head><body lang="EN-IN"link="#0563C1" vlink="#954F72">         Please share 
      <divclass="WordSection1"><p class="MsoNormal"><spanstyle="font-          company details
      family:&quot;Calibri&quot;,sans-serif;color:black">Please share company 
      details</span></p><divclass="MsoNormal" align="center"style="text- 
      align:center"><hr size="2"width="98%" align="center"></div> 
      <pclass="MsoNormal">

43    </style></head><body lang="EN-IN"link="#0563C1" vlink="#954F72">           Can you send 
      <divclass="WordSection1"><p class="MsoNormal"><spanstyle="font-            some project 
      family:&quot;Calibri&quot;,sans-serif;color:black">Can you send            info for west 
      some project info for west region ofIndia</span></p><p class="MsoNormal">  region ofIndia
      <spanstyle="font-family:&quot;Calibri&quot;,sans-serif;color:black">

38    </style></head><bodylang="EN-IN" link="#0563C1"vlink="#954F72"><div         Price of Mono
      class="WordSection1"><pclass="MsoNormal"><span style="font-                 perc
     family:&quot;Calibri&quot;,sans-serif;color:black">Price of Mono perc</span> 
     </p><divclass="MsoNormal" align="center"style="text-align:center"><hr 
     size="2"width="98%" align="center"></div><pclass="MsoNormal"><b>
```

My code looks like -

```
word1 = "sans-serif; color:black">"
word2 = "</span></p>"

df['text'] = s.split(word1)[1].split(word2)[0]
```

This will return the text between word1 and word2. But currently not working. My logic is to extract the mail body or information from a text where text lies between word1 and word2.

Answer (score 3):

Use `BeautifulSoup` to parse HTML

**Ex:**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
df['text'] = df['email'].apply(lambda x: BeautifulSoup(x, "html.parser").find("p", class_="MsoNormal").text)
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
0        Iam not interested. \nPlease unsubscribe me. 
1                       Please share company \ndetails
2    Can you send \nsome project info for west regi...
3                                 Price of Mono perc\n
Name: text, dtype: object
```

Edit as per comment

```
def getText(val):
    soup =BeautifulSoup(val, "html.parser")
    try:
        return soup.find("p", class_="MsoNormal").text
    except:
        return ""

df['text'] = df['email'].apply(getText)
```

Comment: I tried the same thing with `lxml` parser. It didn't work. Any reason why?

Comment: @Rakesh - it's not working...give me error - "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'"

Comment: @bigbounty. Sorry i dont know why it does not work with `lxml`

Comment: @PallaviVerma Looks like some of your column does not have a `p` tag with `class=MsoNormal`. I have edited solution to handle the error.  Also it would be better if you can identify the correct identifier in your data. Example in the above snippet i have used `p` with `class=MsoNormal`

Comment: @Rakesh - Thanks for your quick help...just wanted to know is it better to convert my entire data frame to lower case and then identifier with ("p", class_="msonormal"). any thought??

Answer (score 0):

Try selecting with regular expression:

```
sans-serif; color:black\">(.*)</span></p>
```

link to regex101 sample: https://regex101.com/r/oPihDO/4